column does not exist when function return query execute plpgsql
I've below plpgsql function -
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_query(part_id integer)
RETURNS TABLE (
  event_at timestamp,
  id integer,
  code varchar,
  is_test boolean
)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE 
AS $function$
DECLARE
    query varchar := format("SELECT date_trunc('hour', event_at),
               id,
               code,
               is_test
        FROM metric_events_%s
         event_at < date_trunc('hour', NOW() - interval '1 hour')
         != 0", part_id);
    
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', query;
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE query;
END $function$;

When I run the query like select end_to_end_query(4); I get below error -

ERROR:  column "SELECT date_trunc('hour', event_at),
             id,

             code,

             is_test" does not exist

LINE 1: SELECT format("SELECT date_trunc('hour', event_at),


A few issues with this post: first, you haven't asked a question, you've only made statements; second, you've referenced two functions (end_to_end_query and billing_event_partition_index_new) that are neither defined in the post nor standard in PostgreSQL; third, "s don't enclose text, they enclise identifiers. I assume the intended question is "Why is this exception raised?" Even better, instead of using dynamic SQL to force selection against a particular table partition, allow PostgreSQL to determine the appropriate partition based on query parameters.

@JohnH I updated the post. Do you mind deleting the comment?


As immediately pointed out by @JohnH, you just picked the wrong quote character. String constants use single ', dollar $$ or named dollar $abc$ quotes, while double quotes " are for identifiers: here's the documentation on that.

You can nest named dollar quotes, which is useful with dynamic SQL.

This invocation of date_trunc() will result in a timestamp with time zone because you gave it a now() which outputs a timestamptz, not plain timestamp:



Name
Result data type
Argument data types




date_trunc
interval
text, interval


date_trunc
timestamp with time zone
text, timestamp with time zone


date_trunc
timestamp with time zone
text, timestamp with time zone, text


date_trunc
timestamp without time zone
text, timestamp without time zone


now
timestamp with time zone




so you need to change your signature or downcast.

By default, use text not varchar. Most functions expect and return text, so using varchar instead will likely result in errors related to casting, coercion, signature mismatch, return type mismatch etc.

You forgot a WHERE clause in your dynamic query. You also don't need to compare a boolean-yielding inequality to a !=0. If you're afraid the inequality could result in a null and you wish to handle that differently, you can add conditions involving is not null.


Demo at db<>fiddle:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_query(part_id integer)
RETURNS TABLE (
  event_at timestamptz, --timestamptz is preferable
  id integer,
  code text, --text is a better choice than varchar
  is_test boolean
)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE 
AS $function$
DECLARE
    query varchar := format(
        $dynsql$ --double quotes replaced with named dollar quotes
        SELECT date_trunc('hour', event_at),
               id,
               code,
               is_test
        FROM metric_events_%s --added missing `WHERE clause`
        WHERE event_at < date_trunc('hour', NOW() - interval '1 hour') 
        --unnecessary `!=0` removed
        $dynsql$ , part_id);
    
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', query;
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE query;
END $function$;

select * from my_query(1);




event_at
id
code
is_test




2024-04-08 06:00:00+00
1
code1
f


2024-04-08 07:00:00+00
2
code2
f



As also already mentioned by JohnH, it does seem an awful lot like you're trying to emulate partitioning, which is built-in. Starting with version 10, it's declarative:
create table metric_events (
  event_at timestamptz,
  id integer,
  code text,
  is_test boolean) partition by range(event_at);

alter table metric_events attach partition metric_events_1
    for values from (now()+'-4h') to (now()+'-1h');

select tableoid::regclass,* from metric_events where event_at>now()+'-5h';




tableoid
event_at
id
code
is_test




metric_events_1
2024-04-08 06:36:50.937278+00
1
code1
f


metric_events_1
2024-04-08 07:36:50.937516+00
2
code2
f



tableoid is a system column that can always tell you which actual table/partition a row came from.
You can automate partition management with pg_partman extension.
I'm adding negative interval constants because the + operation on a timestamp(tz) is assumed to take interval as the right operand without having to type it out. Subtracting a positive constant with a - would require explicit ::interval cast, because it accepts either an interval or another timestamp(tz) as the right operand.



Name
Left arg type
Right arg type
Result type




+
timestamp without time zone
interval
timestamp without time zone


-
timestamp without time zone
interval
timestamp without time zone


-
timestamp without time zone
timestamp without time zone
interval



